# Jodatime: Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition (daylight savings time 'gap')

Tags: android, jodatime

This crash happened 2 days ago and I can't understand why. Everything has been working perfectly for 1 year:

```
Fatal Exception: org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException Value 2 for hourOfDay is not supported: Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition (daylight savings time 'gap'): 2019-03-31T02:09:00.000 (Europe/Paris)
```

My code:

```
DateTime dtToRefresh = mDateTime != null ? mDateTime : DateTime.now();
                        dtToRefresh = dtToRefresh.secondOfMinute().setCopy(0);
                        dtToRefresh = dtToRefresh.millisOfSecond().setCopy(0);
                        dtToRefresh = dtToRefresh.hourOfDay().setCopy(hourOfDay);
                        dtToRefresh = dtToRefresh.minuteOfHour().setCopy(minute);
```

The crash started on:

```
dtToRefresh = dtToRefresh.hourOfDay().setCopy(hourOfDay);
```

"hourOfDay" is an hour from a datetime picker (classic process).

Have you got some investigation ways?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For paris Daylight Saving Time is started on March 31st so from that day your code is getting crash. So you are not implemented your code to support dst time.

If you are taking time manually means you need to implement DST time for that timezone. If it is taking system time means no problem.

Solution:

Catch the exception and try to add 1 hour or subtract one hour which is applicable.

```
 try 
 {
   DateTime dtToRefresh = mDateTime != null ? mDateTime : DateTime.now();
                    dtToRefresh = dtToRefresh.secondOfMinute().setCopy(0);
                    dtToRefresh = dtToRefresh.millisOfSecond().setCopy(0);
                    dtToRefresh = dtToRefresh.hourOfDay().setCopy(hourOfDay);
                    dtToRefresh = dtToRefresh.minuteOfHour().setCopy(minute);
 } 
 catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) 
 { 
    dttoRefresh.plusHours(1);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply, but how can I do that?

Comment: From where mDateTime is coming?

Comment: I've added solution

Comment: Thank you very much @Magudesh!